# Identity Server 3 unit testing authorization code flow

Tags: unit-testing, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I am using Identity Server 3 for implementing OAuth2 authentication.

I want to unit test the authorization code flow.

I am able to make a GET request to the authorize endpoint and get back a signin value.

I would like to authenticate the user to get the authorization code back and then use the code to get the access token.

I need some help with authenticating the user using the login link provided in a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have the same situation as I do, but the steps I needed to do are;

1. GET from /connect/authorize supplying made-up nonce and state. From the result you need to gather the signin param and fish out the anti-forgery token from the HTML. Also note that there should be a couple of cookies, sign-in and another anti-forgery token. DO NOT mess with those, keep them
2. POST to /login with the signin param and form fields of username, password and anti-forgery token AND send in the cookies.
3. Gather the session from the resulting cookies OR check the HTML for an error message